# Cant get powershell script to work on button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, button

Spend many hours on a home light control app. When i use the below code in powershell the cmd.exe command gets over te a remote machine and execute it to turn off the lights. This part is working.

alllightsoff.ps1

```
$options=New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName HTPC -UseSSL -SessionOption $options
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\HarmonyHubControl\Release\x86\HarmonyHubControl.exe" 10.90.1.8 issue_device_command 42458302 Light7
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\HarmonyHubControl\Release\x86\HarmonyHubControl.exe" 10.90.1.8 issue_device_command 42458303 LightOff
Exit-PSSession
```

Now i have a C# scripts and i had it working before on a linux machine with ssh. when i press a button this code was executed.

```
using (var ssh = new SshClient(CreateConnectionInfo()))
{
    ssh.Connect();
    ssh.RunCommand("/home/iiidefconiii/HarmonyHubControl/HarmonyHubControl 10.90.1.8 issue_device_command 42458302 Light7");
    ssh.RunCommand("/home/iiidefconiii/HarmonyHubControl/HarmonyHubControl 10.90.1.8 issue_device_command 42458303 LightOff");
    ssh.Disconnect();
}
```

I moved over to a windows computer instead of ssh, linux. So i need to throw that powershell code from out that button.

```
using System.Management.Automation;
```

Applied the reference, so this should be ok for now.

I figured out that that the following piece of code does the job, but i dont wanne create *.ps1 files for each command, instead i want the powershell command directly the app itself

```
private void Sleep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddScript(@"D:\Desktop\alllightsoff.ps1");
    ps.Invoke();
}
```

If i insert

```
        private void Sleep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            param([string]$command)
            $options = New - PSSessionOption - SkipCACheck - SkipCNCheck
            Enter - PSSession - ComputerName HTPC - UseSSL - SessionOption $options
            cmd.exe / c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\HarmonyHubControl\Release\x86\HarmonyHubControl.exe" 10.90.1.8 issue_device_command 42458302 $command
            Exit - PSSession
        }
    }
```

Im also getting errors

Comment: Are you saying that you want to convert your powershell code to C# code, and put that in the `Click` event?

Comment: no, i just wanne pipe the code over a powershell session. I i click the button a powershell command should run.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize your script:

```
param([string]$command)
$options=New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName HTPC -UseSSL -SessionOption $options
cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Home Control\HarmonyHubControl\Release\x86\HarmonyHubControl.exe" 10.90.1.8 issue_device_command 42458302 $command
Exit-PSSession
```

Pass the parameter of the command to the script.

Comment: it has to be at the top of the script - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554301.aspx

Comment: Thank you but im not really understand this, sorry im a basic user

Comment: this is a new script...executes one single parameterized command named command...then youll update your c# code to pass the command you want to execute

Comment: Could you show me an example? in the full code? i might understand it better then